# Trigger that alters stock table when Item is sold

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Is this the syntax correct for trigger to alter stock table when item is sold?

```
create trigger tr_stockquant
on tbl_ticket for insert, update, delete as $$
begin
update s set stockQty = s.stockQty - isnull(i.Qty,0) + isnull(d.Qty,0)
from tbl_stock s
left join inserted i
on s.itemID = i.itemID
left join deleted d on itemID = s.itemID
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Questions usually have a `?` in them.

Comment: I understand your question, but I cannot understand your code.  Please convert to a code block and add appropriate line breaks (make it a code block by adding four spaces after each line break).  Also, you should test it.  Does it do what you want it to do?  If not, then you can come back.   Tell us what you want it to do and what it actually does, and we may be able to help you better.

Comment: I get error syntax near line on when run through psql i am trying to update the stock quantity table when an item is sold from the ticket table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to create a proper function first, and then adhere to the syntax and semantics of the [CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtrigger.html) statement.

So first you create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION alter_stock_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF tg_op = 'INSERT' THEN
            ...
        ELSIF tg_op = 'UPDATE' THEN
            ...
        ELSIF tg_op = 'DELETE' THEN
            ...
        ENDIF
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

And then you can create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER alter_stock_table_trigger
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON tbl_ticket
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE alter_stock_table();
```

Google will help you find more examples for how to define your function.
For example, [this page](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-trigger-for-beginners/) gives a brief introduction.